# Trying to load an XML into a class object using XElement and LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML

```
<Workflow Name="Workflow1">
<Parameter Name="Parameter1">Value1</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="Parameter2">Value2</Parameter>
<Environment Name="Environment1" Type="Typ1">     
  <DataCenter Name="DC1" DeployEnvironmentName="blah"/>
</Environment>
<Environment Name="Environment2" Type="Typ2">     
  <DataCenter Name="DC2" DeployEnvironmentName="blah"/>
</Environment>
```

I am trying to read this XML into the following objects

```
class Workflow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Environment> Environments { get; set; }
}

class Environment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EnvironmentType Type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DataCenter> DataCenters { get; set; }        
}

class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class DataCenter
{
public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DeployEnvironmentName { get; set; }
}
```

using the following expression

var root = XElement.Load(filePath);

```
    var workflows =
        root.Elements("Workflow")
            .Select(
                e =>
                new Workflow
                {
                    Name = e.Attribute("Name").Value,
                    Parameters = e.Elements("Parameter")
                         .Select(p => 
                         new Parameter { Name = p.Attribute("Name").Value, Value = p.Value }),
        Environments = e.Elements("Environment").Select(
                                   p =>
                                   new Environment
                                   {
                                       Name = p.Attribute("Name").Value,
                                       Type = (EnvironmentType)Enum.Parse(typeof
                                       (EnvironmentType), p.Attribute("Type").Value, true),
                                       DataCenters = p.Elements("DataCenter").Select(
                   dc => new DataCenter { 
                                              Name = dc.Attribute("Name").Value,                                      DeployEnvironmentName = dc.Attribute         
                                              ("DeployEnvironmentName").Value                                      })
                                    });
                });
```

I keep getting a syntax error. For some reason, it doesn't seem to like these nested expressions. Anyone know what could be going wrong or know of a better way to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide error message?

Comment: *I keep getting a syntax error.* - What error? Where? What debugging have you done so far and what have you found out? You need to isolate the problem further. A good starting point would be breaking down that *enormous* Linq expression into a good few lines so you can actually debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove this semicolon

```
              Name = p.Attribute("Name").Value,
              Type = (EnvironmentType)Enum.Parse(typeof
             (EnvironmentType), p.Attribute("Type").Value, true),
              DataCenters = p.Elements("DataCenter").Select(
               dc => new DataCenter { 
                                      Name = dc.Attribute("Name").Value,                                      DeployEnvironmentName = dc.Attribute         
                                     ("DeployEnvironmentName").Value                                      })
                                });
                                 ^^^
            });
```

You shouldn't use semicolons in [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), you should separate the properties with comma.

Answer (score -1):

Your XML file seems to be broken. The `Workflow`tag was never closed.